# can't build angular app due to httpClient response data array throwing typescript build issue

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, build-error

Hello been out of the coding game for a few years and I am ramping up on Angular 8 (not enjoying it!) I can run ng serve and everything is ok but if I try to build I am getting an error here

```js
userD() {
  // TODO User Angular Service will get to that later.
  var aToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + aToken);

  this.httpClient.get( 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/user', { headers } )
  .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.users = res.data.result; // it doesn't like the .data.result part in build
    console.log(this.users);
  });
}
```

I am using //@ts-ignore for now, not ideal but I don't know why it has a problem with going in to the array if i have it as res it's ok.

Any information would be very helpful to help me understand this. Thank you.

NB: EDIT 
Here is the json
and I want to extract to this results object to then use For in the html to loop through
     {"status":"200", "data": {"result":{"id":3,"name":"patrick lord","email":"patrick@larvel.io","email_verified_at":null,"phone":"123456789","profilePic":71,"created_at":"2019-09-19 19:43:04","updated_at":"2019-09-19 19:43:04","stripe_id":null,"card_brand":null,"card_last_four":null,"trial_ends_at":null,"gender":"male","Address1":"i don't live here S","Address2":"232","City":"Clearfield","Country":"USA","Zip_Post":"55550","YouTube"}}}

Comment: Why would an array (`res: any[]`) have a `data` property?

Comment: hey JB thanks for replying data is in the response not a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Explanation

JB's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070613/cant-build-angular-app-due-to-httpclient-response-data-array-throwing-typescrip#comment102536788_58070613) hits the nail on the head: you're getting a TypeScript error because the `any[]` type *doesn't have a `data` property*; by definition, `any[]` is expecting *anything*, with the only restriction being that the input must be an object of type `Array`.

### But why the error in `build --prod` and not `serve`?

You're getting the error on `ng build --prod` and *not* on `ng serve` is because the default Angular environment enforces `strict` (as in "strict adherence to typing and syntax") on `--prod`, but *doesn't* enforce `strict` in the local dev environment.  This is so you can play around and figure stuff out more easily when developing locally, where sloppy syntax is less of an issue, before cleaning up your code for production use.  It took me a bit to wrap my head around this, too, but it's a Good Thing(tm) :P

## The Justification

JavaScript lets you do pretty much whatever you want: it has no clue what `res` is going to look like, but it assumes you know what you're doing and if you say `res` is going to have a property called `data`, it just rolls with it.

This is great if you've got a small project, or if you're the *only* person who's ever going to work on it, but it starts to get tricky when the project gets larger, or if you have multiple developers submitting code.  *You* know that `res` has a `data` property, but how does *Samantha* know that?

### Enter `TypeScript`

[TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) is JavaScript...with Types.  Types provide the *shape* of a given object, so everybody involved (including the TypeScript transpiler) knows what's up.  When you say `res: any[]` , what TS hears is "object `res` is going to be an `Object` of type `Array`"; we *haven't*, however, told TS anything about the member-items *within* the array, and since it doesn't know what *kind* of array `res` is going to be, the only things to which we have access are the generic methods and properties of the `Array` type, itself.

## The Fix

So, what do we need to do *instead* of `(res: any[])` to make `this.users = res.data.result;` work?

### Define an Interface for the ResponseObject

We need to start by telling TS what to expect with a little more detail:

```js
export interface ResponseObject {
  data: {
    result: {};
  }
}
```

Now TS knows that there's an `Object` called `ResponseObject` that has (at minimum) a `data` property, and that `data` property is *itself* an `Object` that has (again, at minimum) a property called `result`.

### Tell TypeScript to expect our ResponseObject

We can plug this into our subscription call like this:

```js
.subscribe( (res: ResponseObject) => {
  this.users = res.data.result; // now it totally DOES like the .data.result part in build --prod!
  console.log(this.users);
});
```

## Wait a sec...

You may notice that `res` is no longer expected to be an object of type `Array`;  based on the code you posted and the fact you said it worked via `ng serve`, it sounds like you're expecting a single ResponseObject that delivers an array of UserObjects as the payload on the `data.result` property; if so, the code sample above should work fine.

If, however, our `.get()` really *is* returning an *array* of ResponseObjects, we're going to need to do some extra work.

### Dealing with an array of ResponseObjects

Let's change up our interface declaration, first:

```js
export interface ResponseObject {
  status: number;  /*  It's OK to exclude things we don't need,
      but, the status property is going to come in handy when
      we eventually want to write a catch statement for cases
      when the call returns an error instead of the data we
      wanted  */
  data: {
    /*  you can also split up your interface declarations to
        make them easier to read; this has the added benefit of
        allowing us to more easily access the sub-properties of
        our payload later on  */
    result: UserObject;  /*  we're expecting a single
        UserObject per ResponseObject in this scenario,
        otherwise we'd use:  */
    // result: UserObject[];
  }
}

export interface UserObject {
  /*  remember to use the generic type names (lowercase 'string'),
      not Primitives (Capitalized 'String') in your interface
      declaration, otherwise you'll get more errors  */
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email?: string;  /*  the question mark lets you define a
    property that *may* exist, but may not.  Useful if your
    target API only includes parameters with non-null values
    in the ResponseObject   */
  // ...all the other things you want and think will exist
}
```

Then we can mix up our subscription call:

```js
.subscribe(
  // we tell subscribe that we're expecting an array of ResponseObjects
  (res: ResponseObject[]) => {
    /*  users needs to be defined as an array to hold onto
        multiple UserObjects; we're clearing it here to make
        sure we're only dealing with fresh data and specifying
        that it will be an array of type UserObject  */
    this.users: UserObject = [];

    /*  the data property isn't a property of the *array*, but
        of each array *member-item*, so we need a loop  */
    res.forEach(
      (res_item: ResponseObject) => {
        // add the response object data to our users array
        this.users.push(res_item.data.result);
    });

    // now console log should properly show our array of UserObjects!
    console.log(this.users);
  }
);
```

***n.b.,*** Please don't forget to mark this as the Accepted Answer if it does, in fact, answer your question satisfactorily.  If someone comes along with a better or more concise answer to your question you can always change the Accepted Answer after-the-fact.

Cheers!

Comment: so yea my response is cause the json i get back has this structure sorry I was rushing and should have included this.
{"status":"200",
"data":
{"result":{"id":3,"name":"patrick lord","email":"patrick@larvel.io","email_verified_at":null,"phone":"123456789","profilePic":71,"created_at":"2019-09-19 19:43:04","updated_at":"2019-09-19 19:43:04","stripe_id":null,"card_brand":null,"card_last_four":null,"trial_ends_at":null,"gender":"male","I don't live here S","Address2":"23223","City":"Clearfield","Country":"USA","Zip_Post":"99898","YouTube"}}}

Comment: This is an amazing answer! You have broken down my issue and explained the answer. I wish more answers were done in this way. thank you so much for taking the time to put together this answer. "Samantha" will def thank you to HA

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!